# How to use SCSS with Express ? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, express, sass

Is there any way to use SCSS with Express ?

I tried with :

`app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['scss'] }));`

But it gives me an error :

`DEBUG: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you can use it that way i.e. as a built in module. The author of ExpressJS himself said that it is not possible. I was having the same problem and found out that you either had to use SASS.js or LESS. 
Refer this: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/787 
I recommend you to use [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/)!

Comment: For those stumbling on to the question, you may have some luck with:  https://npmjs.org/package/node-jade-compress

Answer (score 1):

Take a look @ Node-sass -- [NPM Package](https://npmjs.org/package/node-sass) | [Github](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass)

This is a wrapper around the C/C++ library libsass.